# Kernel module alias

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When compiling  different versions of the Linux kernel, every now and then I see some drivers being dropped in favor of others.

For instance, the commit `5772dcaa790851ec068afcd0d1f160d801b1126e` drops (removes) the IBM driver for the Xirlink C-it Camera, located in `drivers/media/video/usbvideo/ibmcam.c` in the v2.6.37 branch. The newer driver appears in v2.6.38 at `drivers/media/video/gspca/xirlink_cit.c`.

For that particular driver, I see that all devices supported by the newer driver are supported by the old , as written in its `usb_device_table`, defined in `xirlink_cit.c`. However, I don't see any alias from the newer driver module towards the older. I know the existence of the `MODULE_ALIAS` macro, but in this case in particular, I don't see it being used.

That said, I want to know all possible ways in which aliases can be programatically defined.
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Why does there need to be an alias from the newer to the older? That's not usually how drivers are selected anyway.

Comment: Let us suppose that the older would generate a module named ibmca. To load it manually, you would use 'modprobe ibmca'. But if the name of the module changes (now it is xirlink), you cannot reuse the previous name , which might result in errors when migrating between kernels.

Comment: 99.99999% of the time the module name is never used though.

Comment: You are right, but having the alias defined anywhere is useful in identify traceability among drivers being added/removed, as it is the case with  Xirlink C-it Camera.